# JavaScript equivalent for Emmet?

Tags: javascript, sublimetext3, atom-editor, emmet

Is there a JS equivalent to Emmet (HTML/CSS only)?

It'd be nice to type `cl[tab]` and have `console.log()`

Comment: you could use one of many available text expander's .read more at : http://www.mburnette.com/blog/best-textexpander-snippets-web-developers

Answer (score 0):

Emmet's default is to not support JS files. So you will need to add a keyboard shortcut to tab complete in JSX files.

Answer (score 0):

Meh, just ended up writing my own snippets. There are a few packages out there but none of them seem as well put together as Emmet.